# Function Doesn't Work When Called Within Object

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have the following code:

```
// auto_suggest.js
function AutoSuggest(textboxElem, resultElem, url) {
    this.textboxElem = textboxElem;
    this.resultElem  = resultElem;
    this.url         = url;
    this.registerEvent();
}

AutoSuggest.prototype = {
    registerEvent: function() {
        this.textboxElem.onkeyup = this.getSuggestions;
    },
    getSuggestions: function() {
        // This doesn't work either: this.loadResponse("some data");
        $.get(this.url, { text: this.textboxElem.value }, this.loadResponse);
    },
    loadResponse: function(data) {
        // Not called
        this.resultElem.innerHTML = data;
    }
};

// suggest.html
<script src="jquery-1.6.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="auto_suggest.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script>
$(function() {
    var suggest = new AutoSuggest(document.getElementById("suggest"), 
                                  document.getElementById("result"), 
                                  "result.txt");
        // This DOES work: suggest.loadResponse("123");
});
</script>

<input type="text" id="suggest" /><br>
<div id="result"></div>
```

The function `loadResponse` refuses to be called from within the object, but from the outside it is fine. What could be the problem?

Comment: I don't understand the problem.  `suggest.loadResponse("123");` should work from outside the object, `this.loadResponse("123");` from within....

Comment: Does `AutoSuggest.loadResponce` work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code

```
this.textboxElem.onkeyup = this.getSuggestions;
```

should be

```
var t = this;
this.textboxElem.onkeyup = function() {
    t.getSuggestions();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The AJAX callback (`AutoSuggest.loadResponse`) is, by default, passed the `jqXHR` object as its context (`this` value).  You need to override this by passing the `context` option to [`$.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax).  Replace your `$.get` function with this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: this.url,
    type: 'GET',
    data: { text: this.textboxElem.value },
    success: this.loadResponse,
    context: this
});
```

This makes jQuery set `this` to the correct value.

Comment: +1 Alternatively, you could use `$.proxy()`. `$.get(this.url, { text: this.textboxElem.value }, $.proxy(this,"loadResponse"));`